# Retrieving memory block from binary file

Tags: c++, performance, search, binaryfiles

The overall goal is to search and read from a binary file as fast as possible. For a given finite set of parameters, p_1, p_2, ... , p_n, I want to be able to search a binary file and retrieve the contents corresponding to the parameters. The general idea I have is to somehow create a (hash?) map between the parameter set {p_i} and the starting memory locations that correspond to the {p_i}. Of course, I will also need to know how many bytes to read but that will be determined by the {p_i} that determines the object to read. The code will be written in C++.

So, I guess my questions are:

1- What is the fastest way to achieve the goal of searching a binary file?

2- Does my idea above make sense at all? If yes, would it be the most efficient way?

I'll be happy to answer any follow-up questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `fstream::tellg()` to get the file position before reading each object, and put that into the map.

Comment: You know there are already a few million solutions to this problem. Punch "database" or "index" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: How big is the file? A standard solution is to memory-map the file and then just use pointer arithmetic.

Comment: How do you know, that a naïve implementation isn't going to be fast enough, and that you need a faster one, without even profiling?

Comment: Barmar: Cool -- thanks for the *useful* comment!
DavidSchwartz: Thanks for the reply, but it's not very useful.
@KerrekSB: The file is ~60 MB. And yes, the memory-map + pointer arithmetic is what I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The big data solution is to divide the rows of data into key and payload.  Instead of using the letter p for key's, consider using k.  That way, you can use p for payload.

The key contains the hash map, or multi-map if there are key duplicates <sup>1</sup>.  These keys are indexed solely on the primary search key(s) K<sub>n</sub>.

The values of the hash map or hashed multi-map are positions into the payload file containing P<sub>n</sub>.  Depending on the sparsity <sup>2</sup> of your payload data and other related factors, the positioning may be any of the following.

- A range with a starting and ending byte or block index
- An index into only fixed length records
- The starting byte or block of a serialized object that self-disambiguates its length in some way

The details <sup>3</sup> of your expected distribution of search, insertion, deletion, and update operations and whether those operations will be done individually in real time or in bulk will determine what is the optimal protocol to use to add or remove a key and its associated payload.

When query speed is the most important factor, the entire key K and payload P may be regenerated periodically.  If a few nines are required for availability, your K and P may need to be double-buffered, similar to the use of multiple display buffers or ports in gaming display adapters.  (This is because the cost of devising and processing a reliable update mechanism may exceed the cost of doubling the storage capacities of the system.)

The key runs fastest and remains simple if it can be made lean enough to fit in memory.  Otherwise (in big queries) the keys would need to be distributed across the memory of multiple nodes of a cluster by some key division mechanism.  In this later case, the payload may also be distributed across RAID devices in a way that corresponds to key distribution.  If no cluster is available, as a last resort, the hash map can be implemented on disk <sup>4</sup>.

In the search, once you identify your key, K<sub>n</sub>, you can then retrieve your data range for P<sub>n</sub> and construct the object (or objects in the case of a multi-map) from it.

Open the payload file for random access to P and call fseek, lseek, or lseek64, to location P<sub>n</sub> <sup>5</sup>.  These low level calls delegate the locating of the appropriate disk sector for any given P<sub>n</sub> to the operating system, device driver, bus driver, disk firmware, and associated hardware.

---

[1] You can use templates for associative containers from your favorite library or use the std namespace's associative containers.

[2] Sparcity is the degree to which fields in your payload have values.

[3] Another detail is that, if you are building a library, you may wish to identify the difference (via types or status codes) between empty variable length values, unassigned values, unknown values, or indeterminant values.

[4] The design of on-disk hash containers is beyond what can be covered in a simple StackOverflow answer space.

[5] The man pages for these i/o calls and how to open a file descriptor or stream provide details of how to use random access i/o.  There is a plethora of examples online too.